Populate an HTML file's select element via AJAX
I'm a bit stuck, I want to put this PHP list.
<?php
   include 'conexion.php';
   $queri= mysqli_query($est, "SELECT * FROM objeto_gasto order by codigo" );
   ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
  
    <title>lista objetos</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div>
        <select name="objetos">
        <?php 
        while($datos_obj= mysqli_fetch_array($queri))
        {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $datos_obj['codigo'] ?>"><?php echo $datos_obj['detalle']?>     </option>

        <?php
        }
        
        
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>

The connection with the database is working fine, and it's also showing the list in the select of the code shown, but now I want to put that into my HTML page without changing the HTML file to PHP.
Also, to learn and improve my programming skills and put this into practice.

“without changing the HTML file to PHP” - by default, only certain file extensions are processed by PHP, and html is not one of them. Although you could change the system, I think it might add more confusion than benefit. Why don’t you want to change it?

$datos_obj is not a great variable name for an array (which is not an object).

Relevant : Populate  on click using AJAX and PHP

If I understand you correctly, you need this (not complete, sorry)With JavaScript and Ajax
newphp.php
<?php

include_once 'config.php';

$select = $connection->prepare("SELECT username FROM table");
$select->execute();
$select = $select->fetchAll();

foreach ($select as $row) {
    echo $row['username'] . ',';
}
?>


newhtml.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>

        <div id="demo"></div>

        <script>
            function receive() {
                const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.onload = function () {
                    var splits = this.responseText.split(','), select = '';
                    for (let i = 0; i < splits.length - 1; i++) {
                        select += '<option>' + splits[i] + '</option>';
                    }
                    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<select>' + select + '</select>';
                };
                http.open("POST", "newphp.php");
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                http.send();
            }
            receive();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>


Why would you sloppily add an extra trailing comma when you could return json or implode the column of values?

The data it wants to request may not be a single word, and that's why I used a comma to separate @mickmackusa

Delimiting with a comma makes sense.  The extra trailing comma is not clean coding.  implode() avoids this problem.

Yes, the code is not perfect and needs to be modified and worked on @mickmackusa
